# First cohomology of a Galois group with finite base field

Tags: galois-theory, homology-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $l/k$ be a (may be infinite) galois extension with galois group $G$ and  $k$ a finite field with size $q$. Also $k$ and $l$ are given the discrete topology. $G$ is given the Krull topology.

Then consider the Frobenius map $\varphi(\alpha)=\alpha^q$.

Let $a \in Z^1(G,l^*)$ be a 1-cocycle. Then let H be the subgroup Gal$(l/k(a(\varphi)))$ of $G$.

I have already proved that $a$ restricted to $H$ is a group homomorphism: $$a_{|H}:H \to k^*.$$

But I am stuck at proving that $a$ is continuous viewed without restriction: $$a:G \to l^*$$

So far I have that elements in the same coset of $H$ differ by an element from $k^*$ so $a$ has at most $q$ different values on a coset of $H$, so $a$ maps $G$ to a finite, hence compact, subset of $l^*$. Secondly that $a$ is constant on the orbits of the action of $H$ on $G$ by conjugation. So :

$$a(hgh^{-1})=a(g),\quad h\in H, g \in G.$$

I tried to prove from this that $a^{-1}(\{d\})$ has finite index in $G$ for any $d \in l^*$(**EDIT**: I have proved this.), but don't feel confident about this route anymore since this pre-image does not have to be subgroup.

Could someone point me in the right way? Or give me hints of any kind.

Comment: What type of cohomology are you doing? Just standard Galois cohomology? I guess what I'm asking is why this isn't just handled by HT90? I'm sorry if I'm missing something, it's late.

Comment: HT90 only applies on finite extensions or in the infinite case on all cont. 1-cocycles. I need to prove that in this case all 1-cocycles are continuous and hence HT90 can be applied even if it is a infinite extension.

Comment: I have found a prove I think, if someone is interested let me know and I'll post it as answer. Or should I do that anyway?